# How to get the value of strValue and read in Form1_Load?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have one question.
There are 2 forms, (Form1 & Form2).

`Form1` and `Form2` contain 1 textbox and 1 button. After running the application, by clicking a `buttonForm1`, form2 will open.

The user writes "Hello" in the `textboxForm2` and after that the user clicks a 
`buttonForm2` Form2 will hide and "Hello" appears in `textboxForm1`.

So my next plan, I want to add `label1.Text` in Form1. This `label1.Text` will read the same as `textboxForm1`, and `label1.Text` is  placed in `private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)`

According to the code below, `strValue = "Hello"`, How to make `label1.Text = strValue` in `Form1_load`?

When I run the application. An error pops up: `strValue does not exist in the current context`.

```
 //Form1
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Error 
        label1.Text = strValue;
    }
    public void PassValue(string strValue)
    {
        textBox1.Text = strValue;
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 objForm2 = new Form2(this);
        objForm2.Show();
    }
}

 //Form2
 public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    Form1 ownerForm = null;
    public Form2(Form1 ownerForm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.ownerForm = ownerForm;
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.ownerForm.PassValue(textBox1.Text);
        this.Hide();
    }
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
    }
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

My expected result is label1.Text will read the same as (textboxForm1), and label1.Text is placed in private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e).

Answer (score 0):

`strValue` is local to your `PassValue` method. Basically, your `PassValue` is defined as "whatever is passed here as a parameter, let's call it `strValue` **inside this method**." `Form1_Load` is a different method. It does not know anything about `PassValue`'s internal stuff.